# How immutable String value is getting changed without throwing compilation error.

Tags: java, string, immutability

I am reassigning value of a String variable. How this vaule is reassigned wihout thorwing error as String is immutable.

Comment: Please take the [tour] (you get a badge!), have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) I also recommend Jon Skeet's [Writing the Perfect Question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and [Question Checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). We can't help you with code we cannot see.

Answer (score 2):

If you mean, you're doing this:

```
String s = "one";
s = "two";
```

...and wondering why it works, it's because the string is immutable, but the **variable** is not. You can update the variable to point to a different string. You can't change the string it points to so that it has different characters in it.¹

---

¹ *(Well, actually, you can with reflection with some JDK implementations by finding the underlying character array and changing it. But officially, in theory, you can't.)*